For the system $X^TX\beta=X^Ty$, prove that $G\beta$ is unique for any solution $\beta$ iff $Col(G^T) \subset Col(X^T)$
I know that the system of normal equations is always consistent. So, $\beta$ is well-defined. I have trouble with how to start the proof in either direction. Any hint will be appreciated.
